# Inserting an element in given positions (more than one) of a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to add a certain value in loop to a given position of a certain vector. For example:

- the value is 11 and hence `local_index = 11`
- The vector of position I have in input is `neigh = {5,7}`
- The starting vector is `Col={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`

I want to have as output `Col={0,1,2,3,4,5,11,6,7,11,8,9,10}`. This is my first try:

```
vector<long> neigh = {5,7};
long local_index = 11;
auto pos_col = Col.begin();
for (const auto& elem: neigh) {
        Col.insert(pos_col+elem,local_index);
```

I keep getting for the second value of `neigh` a segmentation fault. So my questions are:

- Is this because the insert return a pointer that cannot be re-assigned?
- If the answer to the first question is yes, how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Thank you, so for the proposed task you have an alternative design proposition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [`vector::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) documentation on cppreference.com:

> Causes reallocation if the new `size()` is greater than the old `capacity()`. If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()`, **all iterators and references are invalidated.** Otherwise, **only the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.** The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

Which means that, after your 1st call to `insert()`, your `pos_col` iterator is now invalid for subsequent calls to `insert()`, as it refers to an element before the insertion point.

Try using this instead:

```
auto pos_col = Col.begin();
for (const auto& elem: neigh) {
    Col.insert(pos_col+elem,local_index);
    pos_col = Col.begin();
}
```

Or simply:

```
Col.insert(Col.begin()+elem,local_index);
```

Comment: it seems like OPs `neigh` refers to positions in the original vector. If you dont consider the shift due to previous inserts the elements don't end up at the desired positions. Though I am not sure if my interpretation is right, because OP also seems to have indices off by one. https://godbolt.org/z/ffdMsc9rq

Comment: if my interpretation is right, one can sort `neigh` and shift each insertion by 1 more https://godbolt.org/z/8jrK7P7TW